# Error running './installer -a /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02 --dont-install-useful-gems ' inside Terminal on OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation

I was following a guide/tutorial from [railstutorial.org here](http://railstutorial.org/book) 
and stuck up till Ruby Version Manager (RVM) part below:

```
root# rvm install ree
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 - #fetching (ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02)
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 - #extracting ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02 to /usr/local/rvm/src/ree-1.8.7-2010.02
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 - #installing 
Error running './installer -a /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02  --dont-install-useful-gems ', please check /usr/local/rvm/log/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/install.error.log
There has been an error while trying to run the ree installer. Halting the installation.
```

and this is the install.error.log

```
readline.c: In function ‘username_completion_proc_call’:
readline.c:734: error: ‘username_completion_function’ undeclared (first use in this function)
readline.c:734: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
readline.c:734: error: for each function it appears in.)
make[1]: *** [readline.o] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try running: `rvm update && rvm reload` first. That fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that might be causing issues if you're on OS X 10.6:

1. Do you have the latest version of the [xcode dev tools](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/xcode.html) installed?
2. Try running `rvm_archflags="-arch x86_64"` before rvm install ree

Comment: Hi Beerlington,

Thanks for answering! Yes I'm on OS X 10.6.4

1. My xcode version is 3.2.4, which I believe is the latest.
2. I tried running these rvm_archflags="-arch x86_64" but it doesn't work :(